# MySQL insert update for setting changetime

Tags: mysql

in INSERT UPDATE in MySQL changing the changetime doesn´t work.

THE CODE:

```
INSERT INTO g_ladenpreis 
(ordernumber,changetime,bruttoladenpreis,bruttouvp) 
VALUES (71057375,'2018-07-11 23:55:21',19,39.95) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
bruttoladenpreis = IF(19 != bruttoladenpreis, 19, bruttoladenpreis), 
bruttouvp = IF(19 != bruttoladenpreis, 39.95, bruttouvp), 
changetime = IF(19 != bruttoladenpreis, '2018-07-11 23:55:21', changetime);
```

Changing the two prices works, but the changetime keeps the same.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: FYI, you can use `VALUES(columname)` in the `DUPLICATE KEY` clause instead of repeating the values you're storing.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, do you have an example for using VALUES in the DUPLICATE KEY clause? Every online tutorial uses the notation with = .

Comment: There are examples in the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the assignment to `bruttoladenpreis` last. Otherwise, the `IF()` expressions after it will use the updated value. So if is not `19` when you run the query, it will first change it to `19`, then the next `IF()` tests will fail and they'll keep the values the same.

```
INSERT INTO g_ladenpreis 
(ordernumber,changetime,bruttoladenpreis,bruttouvp) 
VALUES (71057375,'2018-07-11 23:55:21',19,39.95) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
bruttouvp = IF(19 != bruttoladenpreis, 39.95, bruttouvp), 
changetime = IF(19 != bruttoladenpreis, '2018-07-11 23:55:21', changetime),
bruttoladenpreis = IF(19 != bruttoladenpreis, 19, bruttoladenpreis)
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/775d0/1)